# What is the difference between RHEL and RHCOS when it comes to Selinux. csi-driver-registrar sidecar container works without privilege access in RHEL

Tags: rhel, selinux, security-context, registrar, csi-driver

On a RHEL setup, csi-driver-registrar has following securitycontext

```
              securityContext:
                runAsNonRoot: false
                runAsUser: 0
                privileged: false
```

But on RHCOS, csi socket creation fails.

SElinux strace shows `permission denied`.
When I use `privileged: true` it works well.
Could someone help to understand the difference here. I am looking for an option with minimum privileges given to container for security reasons.